# Is a variable not accepting an assignment?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am getting a 'System.NullReferenceException' on line 103:

[image: null1]

It shows that the variable 'r' is null, yet as seen in the picture below line 102 shows that 'this.parentRack' is pointing to an instance of JNV.Rack.  It is as though the assignment on line 102 did not happen.

[image: null4]

When the statements are chained together as shown in line 105 the references all appear to be working.  The value being set ('Altitude') is available using the parent references but yet it throws the NullReferenceException (which is why I broke the statements up to find the problem.)

[image: null3]

Comment: Is this built for `release` or `debug`? (sometimes breakpoints are fishy that way). Also is `.parentSite` a property? Is it possible the `NullReferenceException` is being thrown in its getter or altering the object state?

Comment: My guess would be this.parentRack is returning null I would be interested to know what parentRack Value is in the first example

Comment: It is built for debug.  'parentSite' is another object that has been previously initialized.

Comment: Like Chris said is parentRack a property ?

Comment: Micah, no, the only property is the setAltitude().  I have changed the second picture so you can see the value of parentRack.  parentRack has a 'pointer' to the parentSite and you can see that there are 8 Racks in the rackList - this rack being one of those 8.  So the reference to parentRack yields a valid reference to the parentSite which shows the rack is a member.  It's not that confusing when everything is working.  Here's the architecture, a Site is a location which has several racks  (8 in this case).  Each rack has a number of hardware cards.  "this" is a hardware card with a GPS.

Comment: Another silly question question: do you have any multithreaded access going on here? Could `this.parentRack` be `null` when line 102 executes, but when you hit line 103 the other thread has assigned a value to it? EDIT: Also, you state that the "only property" is `setAltitude()`, but that's a method. Is `parentRack` a _property_ or a _field_?

Comment: Try to instantiate the "r" first like Rack r = new Rack(); before r = this.parentRack;

Comment: Chris, Ding Ding!  The Altitude was being set as the device was being initialized and before it was assigned a parentRack.  By the time I looked at the variable in the GUI it had already been assigned by the other thread.  Silly question?  Not this time!  THANKS!  If you could post that as an answer it might help other people in the future.

Comment: @Thirdy your suggestion about new'ing up object is strange and useless - old value of `r` not going to be taken into account during assignment.

Comment: @CramerTV Alright! Threaded access never fails!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any multithreaded access going on here? Could `this.parentRack` be `null` when line 102 executes, but when you hit line 103 the other thread has assigned a value to it?